# Google Earth Integration

Tags: api, app, google

Can anyone please advise on the latest information in regards to Google Earth and SF integration? Recently we heard there were some changes for licensing on this. We are looking to reference our KML file with Google earth in SF.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a link which i feel will help you, how the integration will help as far as functionality is concerned in salesforce.
http://techcrunch.com/2009/05/06/2338/